# What happens to windows bootloader after installing ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader, mbr

I heard that in mbr partiton scheme, a bootloader is installed before the first partion.Do the grub delete or removes the windows bootloader.Did I can install ubuntu without bootloader, because windows bootloader is there.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB replaces the Windows Bootloader with itself. But you can also start Windows from the GRUB loader screen.

I don't know if you can install Ubuntu without its bootloader, but you can install the Windows Loader again from your Windows system.
I really don't recommend you to set your Windows Loader as default bootloader, GRUB is compatible with both operating systems and you can also customize it as you want.